# MATCH() AGAINST() in boolean mode: order of patterns

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Does the order of the patterns under `against` affect something?
Here is a table I have:

```
create table df_test
(
  t1 text,
  t2 text,
  FULLTEXT df_test_idx (t1 ASC, t2 ASC)
);
```

Here are the rows I have:

```
t1                    |  t2
--------------------------------------------
1word2 1sec71 5word5  |  word2 1sec8 6word6
word1 sec8 5word5     |  word2 sec7 word6
word1 sec8 5word5     |  word2 1sec17 word6
word1 sec7 5word5     |  word2 1sec8 6word6
word1 sec7 5word5     |  word2 sec8 word6
word1 sec7 5word5     |  word2 sec7 word6
sometrash9            |  sometrash10
sometrash7            |  sometrash8
sometrash5            |  sometrash6
sometrash3            |  sometrash4
sometrash13           |  sometrash14
sometrash11           |  sometrash12
sometrash1            |  sometrash2
```

The query `select * from df_test where match(t1, t2) against('6word*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` returns 2 rows, which is expected:

```
t1                    | t2
-------------------------------------------
1word2 1sec71 5word5  | word2 1sec8 6word6
word1 sec7 5word5     | word2 1sec8 6word6
```

The query `select * from df_test where match(t1, t2) against('"word1 sec8"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` also returns 2 rows, which is also expected:

```
t1                    | t2
-------------------------------------------
word1 sec8 5word5     | word2 sec7 word6
word1 sec8 5word5     | word2 1sec17 word6
```

The query `select * from df_test where match(t1, t2) against('"word1 sec8" 6word*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` is expected to merge the results but it returns the same 2 rows as above:

```
t1                    | t2
-------------------------------------------
word1 sec8 5word5     | word2 sec7 word6
word1 sec8 5word5     | word2 1sec17 word6
```

Nevertheless, if I change the sequence of patterns, it returns as expected. The query `select * from df_test where match(t1, t2) against('6word*"word1 sec8"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. The result:

```
t1                    | t2
-------------------------------------------
1word2 1sec71 5word5  | word2 1sec8 6word6
word1 sec7 5word5     | word2 1sec8 6word6
word1 sec8 5word5     | word2 sec7 word6
word1 sec8 5word5     | word2 1sec17 word6
```

Could someone please explain what I am missing?

---

**UPDATE#1:**
The table is InnoDB

SQL to fill the table in:

```
INSERT INTO df_test
VALUES ('1word2 1sec71 5word5', 'word2 1sec8 6word6'),
       ('word1 sec8 5word5', 'word2 sec7 word6'),
       ('word1 sec8 5word5', 'word2 1sec17 word6'),
       ('word1 sec7 5word5', 'word2 1sec8 6word6'),
       ('word1 sec7 5word5', 'word2 sec8 word6'),
       ('word1 sec7 5word5', 'word2 sec7 word6'),
       ('sometrash9', 'sometrash10'),
       ('sometrash7', 'sometrash8'),
       ('sometrash5', 'sometrash6'),
       ('sometrash3', 'sometrash4'),
       ('sometrash13', 'sometrash14'),
       ('sometrash11', 'sometrash12'),
       ('sometrash1', 'sometrash2')
```

---

**UPDATE#2:**
Here is the link to the bug opened with MySQL:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95434

Comment: MyISAM?  or InnoDB?

Comment: Hey, it is InnoDB.

Comment: Can you modify your Question to include the SQL for a test case that we can run?

Comment: Which SQL do you mean exactly? I posted SQL to create a table and each query to index. Do you want me to add an insert statement?

Comment: Yes, insert the rows and perform the SELECT.  Imagine you are receiving a bug report.  You would like to have a test case that fails and that you can run against various versions of the product to see if it is a 'new' bug (ie, a 'regression') or one that has existed a long time.

Comment: Hey @RickJames, sorry for the delay. I've added an insert statement. Now the initial topic contains the create statement, the insert statement and 4 sql queries to perform

Comment: That looks like a bug.  Please fill a report at bugs.mysql.com .